# Splashscreen dont hide in --prod mode on device

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, production

I just develop a small business application with Ionic 4, if I try to build my app with `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` at first everything is working fine, so I sign my APK and install it on my Android 9 Device.

But now the Splashscreen does not hide.

If I try the same step without the `--prod` flag the Applikation starts and works as expected.

Without Prod:

1. Develop
2. `ionic cordova build android --release`
3. The app is working fine on Device

With Prod:

1. Develop
2. `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`
3. App don't hide the Splashscreen

If I try to debug my Application on Device everything is working fine without any errors

I am using Ionic 4.12

app.component.ts

```
initializeApp() {
    this.store.subscribe();
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.initOneSignal();
      timer(3000).subscribe(() => this.showSplash = false);
    });
  }
```

Main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  message: 'dev mod',
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxx'
  }
};
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  message: 'prod mod',
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxx'
  }
};
```

I expect that the app size minimize with prod to 7mb,
the building without the prod flag push the app Sie to 11mb

Comment: Do you have dependencies warning  ? Maybe its that

Comment: Hey Sam no, no warnings only Cordova ionic native warnings if I don't use my phone